# Not able to get expected output for given data in sql using order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-order-by

```
create table test1234(itemid varchar(100),creaetdon datetime,id int) 

insert into test1234 values('1-1001-','2022-05-03 19:06:59.293',111)
insert into test1234 values('1-1001-2-11024-','2022-05-03 19:08:40.447',111)
insert into test1234 values('1-1001-2-11056-','2022-05-03 19:08:27.363',111)
insert into test1234 values('1-1001-2-11269-','2022-05-03 19:08:14.147',111)

insert into test1234 values('1-111-','2022-05-03 19:06:35.537',111)
insert into test1234 values('1-111-2-11024-','2022-05-03 19:09:26.847',111)
insert into test1234 values('1-111-2-11056-','2022-05-03 19:09:16.117',111)
insert into test1234 values('1-111-2-11269-','2022-05-03 19:09:01.407',111)
```

Tried below query but unable to get required data based on order by itemid/createdon or both:

```
select itemid from  test1234 order by itemid
```

Expected output :

```
 1-1001-

1-1001-2-11269-

1-1001-2-11056-

1-1001-2-11024-

1-111-

1-111-2-11269-

1-111-2-11056-

1-111-2-11024-
```

Comment: Add the `SELECT` query you've tried to your question, even if it isn't working.

Comment: "SELECT item FROM test1234 ORDER BY item" will produce the output you've shown. Is this all you want to know?

Comment: You have to separate the value into a letter part and a number part.

Comment: You haven't provided enough imformation about why you expect the desired order. What  is the significance of the various elements to each itemId string, what is the relevance of *creaetdon* to the ordering. What is the relevance of `Id` to the problem, a duplicate value is not an Id of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

```
select item from test1234 order by itemid.
```

If you need item only then you have to mention that column only in select statement instead of *.

Other wise if you want item column values order by item column value then upi have to mention item column only in order by like below.

```
select item from test1234 order by item
```

Comment: I updated the comment to include your output case also. Refresh and check now